# Extract date after string in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I'm trying to extract dates from a `Notes` column using tidyr's extract function. The data I'm working on looks like this:

```r
dates <- data.frame(col1 = c("customer", "customer2", "customer3"),
                    Notes = c("DOB: 12/10/62
START: 09/01/2019
END: 09/01/2020", "
S/DATE: 28/08/19
R/DATE: 27/08/20", "DOB: 13/01/1980
Start:04/12/2018"),
                    End_date = NA,
                    Start_Date = NA )
```

I tried extracting the date following the string "S/DATE" like this:

```r
extract <- extract(
  dates,
  col = "Notes",
  into = "Start_date",
  regex = "(?<=(S\\/DATE:)).*"  # Using regex lookahead
)
```

However, this only extracts the string "S/DATE:", not the date after it. When I tried this on regex101.com, it works as expected.

Thanks. Ibrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method can be like this one also. (Assuming that you need either of `S/DATE` or `START` as your expected new column name is Start_date).  If however all such values aren't required you may easily modify this syntax.

Explanation -

- In the innermost expr `Notes` column has been splitted into list by either of these separators `:` or `\n`.
- In this list, blanks are removed then
- In the modified list item next to `Start` or `S/Date` is extracted using `sapply` which simplifies the list into a vector (if possible)
- lastly `lubridate::dmy` is used in outermost expr.

```
sapply(strsplit(dates$Notes, 
                 "[: | \n]"), 
       function(x) subset(x, x != "")[1 + which(toupper(subset(x, x != "")) %in% c("S/DATE", "START"))])

[1] "09/01/2019" "28/08/19"   "04/12/2018"
```

If you'll wrap the above in `lubridate::dmy` dates will be correctly formatted too

```
dmy(sapply(strsplit(dates$Notes, 
                        "[: | \n]"), 
               function(x) subset(x, x != "")[1 + which(toupper(subset(x, x != "")) %in% c("S/DATE", "START"))]))

[1] "2019-01-09" "2019-08-28" "2018-12-04"
```

Further, this can be passed into dplyr pipes, so as to simultaneously create a new column in your `dates`

```
dates %>% mutate(Start_Date = dmy(sapply(strsplit(Notes, 
                                                  "[: | \n]"), 
                                         function(x) subset(x, x != "")[1 + which(toupper(subset(x, x != "")) %in% c("S/DATE", "START"))])))

       col1                                             Notes End_date Start_Date
1  customer DOB: 12/10/62\nSTART: 09/01/2019\nEND: 09/01/2020       NA 2019-01-09
2 customer2              \nS/DATE: 28/08/19\nR/DATE: 27/08/20       NA 2019-08-28
3 customer3                 DOB: 13/01/1980\nStart:04/12/2018       NA 2018-12-04
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
s_date <- ifelse(grepl("S/DATE", dates$Notes),
                 sub("^.*\\bS/DATE: (\\S+).*$", "\\1", dates$Notes), NA)
s_date

[1] NA         "28/08/19" NA
```

Note that the call to `grepl` above is needed here, because `sub` by default will return the entire input string (in this case the full `Notes`) in the event that `S/DATE` be *not* found in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is splitting the text and dealing with smaller chunks.

Step by step illustration, with one row of data

```
# Split the text on newlines, yielding dates with labels
dates$Notes %>% head(1) %>% strsplit("\n")

[[1]]
[1] "DOB: 12/10/62"     "START: 09/01/2019" "END: 09/01/2020"
```

Drilling down to the next level

```
# Split each name/value pair on colons
dates$Notes %>% head(1) %>% strsplit("\n") %>% 
    unlist() %>% strsplit(":\\s*")

[[1]]
[1] "DOB"      "12/10/62"

[[2]]
[1] "START"      "09/01/2019"

[[3]]
[1] "END"        "09/01/2020"
```

Extract the individual values

```
# extract a vector of name labels
dates$Notes %>% head(1) %>% strsplit("\n") %>% 
    unlist() %>% strsplit(":\\s*") %>%
    sapply(function(x) x[1])

[1] "DOB"   "START" "END" 


# extract a vector of associated values 
dates$Notes %>% head(1) %>% strsplit("\n") %>% 
    unlist() %>% strsplit(":\\s*") %>%
    sapply(function(x) x[2])

[1] "12/10/62"   "09/01/2019" "09/01/2020"
```

With some clever `dplyr` usage, you'll get a data frame

```
dates %>%
    group_by(col1) %>%
    # summarize can collapse many rows into one or expand one into many
    summarize(
        name = Notes %>% strsplit("\n") %>%
            unlist() %>% strsplit(":\\s*") %>% 
            sapply(function(x) x[1]),
        value = Notes %>% strsplit("\n") %>% 
            unlist() %>% strsplit(":\\s*") %>% 
            sapply(function(x) x[2])
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Result, all of the values separated and ready for further processing

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  col1      name   value     
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     
1 customer  DOB    12/10/62  
2 customer  START  09/01/2019
3 customer  END    09/01/2020
4 customer2 NA     NA        
5 customer2 S/DATE 28/08/19  
6 customer2 R/DATE 27/08/20  
7 customer3 DOB    13/01/1980
8 customer3 Start  04/12/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine `stringr` and `lubridate`:

```
dates %>% 
  mutate(
    Start_Date = 
      sub("\ns/date:", "\nstart:", tolower(Notes)) %>% 
      str_remove_all("(.*\nstart:)|(\n.*)") %>% 
      trimws() %>% 
      lubridate::dmy()
  )

#        col1                                             Notes End_date Start_Date
# 1  customer DOB: 12/10/62\nSTART: 09/01/2019\nEND: 09/01/2020       NA 2019-01-09
# 2 customer2              \nS/DATE: 28/08/19\nR/DATE: 27/08/20       NA 2019-08-28
# 3 customer3                 DOB: 13/01/1980\nStart:04/12/2018       NA 2018-12-04
```

The answer is not as concise, but I find it intuitive and easy to follow the steps.

First I substitute one `start`-pattern with another (`sub`), where I use `tolower` to make all lower caps. Then I remove everything before the start date, and everything after the line change `str_remove_all`. Finally I trim whitespace (`trimws`)  and turn into a date (`lubridate::dmy`).